# Enable PayPal Guest Checkout option is missing

Tags: magento2, paypal-express, guest-checkout

i'm currently testing around in our shop paying via PayPal Plus in sandbox mode.
Paying via paypal is working so far with the sandbox accounts, now i want to activate "**Enable PayPal Guest Checkout**" but the option is simply missing.

version: Magento 2.4 Community

Default Country: Germany (configuration->general)

Merchant Location: Germany (Sales->Payment Methods->Merchant Location)

In the Paypal business account(PayPal Plus is Added): PayPal Account Optional is enabled

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per `vendor/magento/module-paypal/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`, the **Enable PayPal Guest Checkout** setting is not available for Germany:

[image]

If you change the Merchant country to UK for example, you will see the option there.

Comment: That makes me wonder because this page(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/guest-payments/supported-countries/) shows Germany in the list for "Guest payments supported countries" and Magento is using a Shopping Cart procedure as default if i'm correct.

Comment: Check this https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/paypal-countries.html. As you can see, for Germany, only the `PayPal Express Checkout` is available and as the code suggests, the option for guest checkout within paypal express checkout is not available, even if the documentation states otherwise. Code doesn't lie :)

Comment: Interesting here is that if i change the 'Merchant Country' to 'UK' for example, it works, PayPal shows up to pay directly with credit card or debit. On the German PayPal Plus Website it states: "even customers without a PayPal account". Code doesn't lie, but it can be wrong ;) Not sure if this was a misconception or if it has changed in the meanwhile for german PayPal business accounts with PayPal Plus.

Comment: well yes, it can be wrong, what i was trying to emphasize is that although the documentation states that this functionality is available 'on paper', in fact, by checking the code and the application you can clearly see this is not available in Magento. you could try to overwrite this somehow, but i am not sure which are the repercussions. Maybe write to Magento team and sort things out with them?

Comment: Yes, i will consider sending them an email. thx

Comment: sure, no problem. please feel free to come back with feedback so we could mark this topic as closed/ solved.